# How to install pdftools with MacPorts?

Tags: macos, pdf, macports, open-source, sonoma

After installing `R-pdftools` with [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/R-pdftools/) (V2.8.1 on Sonoma) without any error messages I cannot find `pdftools` in Terminal.

What's wrong?

Comment: What tools do you expect to find from this package?

Comment: OTOH, there are 182 (today's count) packages that match `port search pdf | less`. A few appeared to be CLI without the R affiliation.

Comment: I am looking for 'pdftool zip' in order to merge to pdf files. Are there any packages available that are not based on R? 

I found a `pdftools` which I could install via pip but I think I should not mix all my Macport python installations with pip / homebrew, right?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have installed a package for R (a programming language) which lets R programmers manipulate PDF files. It doesn't look like you can call it directly from the terminal.

Usage instructions are [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdftools/pdftools.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Here are a range of PDF-manipulating command line tools that can be installed directly:

**XPDF tools**
https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html

**PDFtk Server:**
https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/

**GhostScript**
You can of  course use [GhostScript](https://www.ghostscript.com) to merge PDFs.
Binaries for Mac are here:
https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/

If you're into python, there are various python libraries that will manipulate PDFs, such as pikePDF.
https://github.com/pikepdf/pikepdf

You could create a workflow using Automator.app or Shortcuts.app, and call it from the CLI, using the `shortcuts` or `automator` commands.

I've also written a suite of python scripts that call macOS APIs to perform various PDF functions:
https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite
(You'll need to install the pyobjc library.)

Comment: thanks for your suggestions! I checked pdf tools but I do not find a tool wherein I can merge two different pdf's side-by-side. 

PDFtk cannot yet be installed on Sonoma as I understand. 

I will check your PDFsuite.

Comment: @Bernd Ah: yes, you're right that XPDF doesn't have a merge tool; but there is some useful stuff. I'd suggest GhostScript is the most powerful and useful.